# Does the Miss Peregrine movie cover the events of both books in the series (i.e. does it also include events from Hollow City)?

Tags: miss-peregrines-home

Is the movie *Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children* a combination of 
the first and second book (*Hollow City*)?

Answer (score 5):

No, it is an adaptation of only the first book.

As is normal with film adaptations, several parts of the book are left out.  For example, only two named ymbrynes appear.

The film's story does however work well in its own right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it partly combined. The creepy amusement park in the film appears in the second book. Still the main story is from the first book though it is pretty much modified.
Hope my answer helped.

Comment: Is there any more in the film from the second book than just the amusement park?